# Points not appearing in main question

Tags: exam

For some reason, the points DO appear in the parts and subparts but it doesn't appear in the main questions in this document. I tried removing the 3 lines between the 2 ** too in case they were causing it. Nothing helped.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,twoside,answers,12pt]{exam}
\usepackage{longtable,graphicx,tabularx,booktabs,amsmath,amssymb,lmodern,textcomp,gensymb,ifpdf,placeins,wrapfig,xfrac,lastpage,floatrow,setspace,cancel,units,booktabs,array,multirow,color,ifthen,zref-abspage,zref-lastpage,multicol,bigints,relsize}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[noabbrev]{cleveref}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}
\onehalfspacing
**\marksnotpoints
\bracketedpoints
\pointsinrightmargin**
\unframedsolutions
\SolutionEmphasis{\color{blue}}

\qformat{{\large \textbf{Question \#\thequestion}}\hfill        \vspace{0.4cm}}

    \begin{document}


        \begin{questions}

            \question[10]
            Find the distance 
        \end{questions}
    \end{document}
```

If I have parts in the question, they do appear in the right margin like [10] as desired...

I gave `\pointpoints{ mark}{ marks}` but I don't get "marks" after the parts and one question is messing up.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You have redefined the appearance of your question. Therefore, the documentclass does not know, where to put the points. Add `\thepoints` to where ever you like:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[addpoints,letterpaper,twoside,answers,12pt]{exam}
\usepackage{lmodern,setspace}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\onehalfspacing
\marksnotpoints
\bracketedpoints
\pointsinrightmargin    
\qformat{{\large \textbf{Question \#\thequestion}}\hfill[\thepoints]\vspace{0.4cm}}

\begin{document}    
    \begin{questions}       
        \question[10]
        Find the distance 
    \end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Off-topic: Do load `siunitx` instead of `units` and `xcolor` instead of `color`

---

Edit: If you want to get rid of the word "marks", replace `\marksnotpoints` by `\pointname{}`. All of this stuff is explained in the well written [manual](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/exam) of `exam`

Comment: This gives [10 marks] beside the main questions but the points for the parts/subparts remains as [10] only. How do I make them both of one type?

Comment: @FahimAbdullah Of which type do you want?

Comment: Rid of the marks is fine as you gave. Thanks. I can imagine it's \pointname{ marks} for the other.

Comment: It seems the parts aren't getting the "marks" when I put \pointname{ marks}. And there is also a weird thing happening here in one question (edited the main post)